# Rails + Active Admin: Display name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin with Ruby on Rails and I am having an issue with the way that some models are shown in the panel.

Taking the class `User` as an example, if I do not define any method to display it friendly, I see `#<User:00000006b47868>`. So Active Admin suggests implementing a method to specify, for each class, how to show it.

According to the documentation (http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html), Active Admin looks for one of these methods to guess what to display, in the following order:

`:display_name, :full_name, :name, :username, :login, :title, :email, :to_s`

So having this method within the `User` class would solve the problem:

```
def display_name
  return self.id.to_s + '-' + self.full_name
end
```

However, before using Active Admin, I was already using the method `display_name` with other purposes (for example, in views) in order to show the user name in a friendly way, and I do not want to show the same in Active Admin panel.

I cannot change the name of the method because I use `display_name` in a lot of files along the project, and changing it would probably introduce bugs in the application.

An ideal solution for this case would be to have something like an `active_admin_name` method that is used by Active Admin to show models in its panel. So the question is:

**Is there any way to have a method that is called by Active Admin instead of `display_name`?** For example, to result in the following order:

`:active_admin_name, :display_name, :full_name, :name, :username, :login, :title, :email, :to_s`

I have searched in Active Admin documentation and in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`, but I could not find a way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|    
  config.display_name_methods = [:active_admin_name, :display_name ...]
end
```

You can find this setting in `lib/active_admin/application.rb`

Comment: I think I do not have that file in my project. I tried creating it and putting that code there, but it did not work. I also tried putting that code in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`, but no good results neither. I have found that in Active Admin source code there is some code like yours: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/application.rb Maybe we have to put it within other file?

Comment: It works for my project which uses AA 0.6.0. I defined `config.display_name_methods = [:admin_display_name, ....]` in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`. Be sure you restart your app.

Comment: @eze.scaruli Should be marked as correct answer. Note that the configuration can be in different places, for me it is in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `:title` key to define it for each page, like this:

```rb
show(title: 'Something') do |record|
  ...
end

# or with a Proc
show(title: ->(record) { record.another_method_to_display }) do |record|
  ...
end
```